# Where Do I Put My Extra Into An ArrayList?

Tags: android-listview, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to make a To-Do-List App for Android. This app has two activities. The main activity is where I have my EditText and Submit button. The second activity has a ListView that will populate the data from the MainActivity EditText.

```
MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     }

      public void goToListView(View view) {        

        EditText eT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterTasks);        
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);      
        intent.putExtra("tasks", eT.getText().toString());       
        startActivity(intent);
     }     
}
```

I believe that the data is being passed correctly because I can put that data into a TextView in the second activity.

My second Activity has the ArrayList and ArrayAdapter setup. My problem is I do not know where to pass the extra into the ArrayAdapter.

```
SecondActivity.java

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<String> arrayListToDo;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterToDo;

      @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);

        arrayListToDo = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayAdapterToDo = new ArrayAdapter<> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        arrayListToDo);
        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapterToDo);

        TextView nameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        nameView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("tasks"));
      }
}
```

I realize that my data will not be saved if I change states. I found that out when I was searching for an answer. My question is where am I supposed to put my extra into the ArrayAdapter? Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a String in that extras. The first question is if that String could contain many different values (separated by "," for example) or if it's just one task.
I assume they can be many since the name of the extra is "tasks".

So having this into account, you have two possibilities:

1) You keep the String parameter and then you parse the content into an array, like:

```
String tasksExtra = getIntent().getExtras().getString("tasks");
String[] tasks = tasksExtra.split(","); // if your separator is the comma.
```

And then you pass the tasks array to the ArrayAdapter:

```
arrayAdapterToDo = new ArrayAdapter<> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        tasks);
```

2) In your MainActivity, you have, for example, an EditText, a "+" button and the submit button. When they user enters the task, he can press the "+" button, this will add the task to a String list (that you can show below), clear the EditText and allow the user to add more tasks.
Then, when the user presses submit, you can pass the String array as an extra:

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("tasks", yourStringArrayList);
```

or

```
intent.putStringArrayExtra("tasks", yourStringArray);
```

and use it directly in the SecondActivity:

```
ArrayList<String> tasks = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayListExtra("tasks");
arrayAdapterToDo = new ArrayAdapter<> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        tasks);
```

or

```
String[] tasks = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayExtra("tasks");
arrayAdapterToDo = new ArrayAdapter<> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        tasks);
```

Comment: I did not know that I needed to parse the string into an array. This is where I was stuck. Your code worked perfectly and now I understand what I did wrong. Thank you so much!